# recorder.js change bit depth, from 16 bits to 24 bits

Tags: javascript, recording

The recordings done with recorder.js are done in 44,100 Hz, 16 bits. How can I change that to 44,100 Hz, 24 bits?

```
 var worker = new Worker(config.workerPath || WORKER_PATH);
        worker.postMessage({
            command: 'init',
            config: {
                sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate
            }
        });
```

Could I add it somehow to the configuration settings?

Comment: ([A reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/44%2C100_Hz) for 44,100 Hz.)